# Is a probability operator on propositions symmetrical?

Tags: probability

What I mean is: does, "It is not probable that..." = "It is probable that not..."? For example, does, "It is 50% probable that..." = "It is probable that 50%..."? Or are we then speaking of two different probability relations? (Is that possibility of multiple probability operators relevant to the considerations raised in Ognjanović[[11](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-23963-2_18)]?)

This question is occasioned by the recent update to the SEP article on [interpretations of probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/), so I would like to quote the epigraph there:

> *Probability is the most important concept in modern science, especially as nobody has the slightest notion what it means.* —Bertrand Russell, 1929 Lecture (cited in Bell 1945, 587)

I certainly(!) have almost always had trouble understanding probabilistic reasoning, to the extent that I have spent most of my life trying to avoid making strong, conscious probabilistic judgments. (Whether I have *subconsciously* made these, well...) So let my question stand for my overarching confusion in this context!

Comment: Please explain a bit the two statements from your question "It is 50% probable that..." = "It is probable that 50%..."  The first statement quantifies the probability of an event as 0.5, that's clear. But what does the second statement mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @JoWehler maybe, "It is 50% probable that some moose is green," vs. "It is probable that 50% of all moose are green." I guess we'd have a quantifier shift then...

Comment: The first statement quantifies a probability, the second quantifies a portion of moose and adds the word "probable" from colloquial language. On which basis could one compare these two statements?

Comment: @JoWehler I will have to defer to those better-versed than I am, in the nuances of probability theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First phrase: yes, this is just common language expressing the rule of subtraction: P(X) = 1-P(X')

Second phrase: no. If it is 50% probable that one moose randomly selected out of all moose is green, then the probability that 50% of all moose are green must be 1 if the moose do not change color over the time in which we are polling moose for pigmentation. (We have exactly one sample set and half of its elements are green.)

If it is 50% probable that one moose randomly selected out of a particular randomly selected bucket of moose is green, and there are an unknown large number of moose buckets, we can make only weak inferences about the statistical distribution of moose buckets. It is probable that we picked a bucket within one standard deviation of the center of the moose density distribution, but that's all we can say about it.

Comment: I am minded to accept this answer, but so am I correct in thinking that you have shown that probability operators, such as they are, are asymmetrical modulo negation positions?

Comment: I don't think boolean negation can take a value other than TRUE or FALSE as an argument, so I'm not sure that question means anything without additional definitions for what it means to negate a non-boolean value.

Comment: Put another way: obviously 1% is not 2% and 2% is not 3% but 3% is not not not 1%. but if we define "neg" to be "express the conjugate", neg 1% is 99% and neg 99% is 1%, so neg (neg 1%) is neg (99%) and so on.